# IOS changed development targets to IOS 8 >= but XCODE still looking for 7 >= appicons

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to make my project support IOS 8 + devices.

I have changed the deployment target as follows:
[image]

I have all the correct assets loaded (they are pasted over for confidentiality in the photo) in the appIcons.asset for IOS 8.0 >= [image]

However, I still get the following issue when trying to publish:
[image]

I am using XCode 6.4. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Cheers!

Comment: What? iOS 8 is included in "iOS version >= 7.0"

Comment: The error is clear - the image is missing. Redo your app icon images.

Comment: @maddy i pasted over them, the images are correct.

Comment: @BensonTommy Tommy what can i do to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to also check the "IOS 7 and later checkbox" and then fill in the required icons.

This is strange, since I am targeting IOS 8.0 and above. Not sure if this is intended or a bug.

Cheers!